# Write a minimal DFA for the language $L = \{(ab)^n \mid n \geq 0\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

> Write a minimal DFA for the language $L = \{(ab)^n \mid n \geq 0\}$

#### My attempt:

I currently haven't completed the solution, but my main problem is to find a simpler solution for this as the procedure I have followed so far doesn't seem to add up.
What I did was:

1) I created a DFA that you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa6Mg.jpg)

2) Now I was following the procedure to minimize the DFA using the Systematic Reduction Method as shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js4oT.jpg) (It isn't complete)

There has to be some way to make a DFA without going through all of this, but I simply can't think of it.

Comment: You seem to be working with $(ab)^n$ rather than the $a^nb^n$ that is (currently) in your title. The language in the title isn't regular, so you won't find a finite automaton recognizing it. If you replace $a^nb^n$  with $(ab)^n$, you'll get a regular language.

Comment: What do you mean by "n!=4"?

Comment: !=  means 'Not Equal To'

Comment: Actually, you have not written a DFA, because a DFA must account for all the inputs, while you consider just the ones that may possibly produce a valid string. Thus, yours is actually a NFA, and I presume this may give trouble when one tries to apply SRM. That being said, if your goal is recognizing the language $L=\{ab\}^*\setminus\{abababab\}$, then the same idea you've applied there used with the intention of describing a DFA actually produces the minimal DFA. There appears not to be much way around the fact that $L$ has a lot of Myhill-Nerode classes.

Comment: That was intentional as adding all the cases from each state would have made the diagram very confusing for me. I intended to make the missing parts to go to a trap state, shown in the state table

Comment: Could you confirm that @andreas-blass is correct and modify your question accordingly?

Comment: @anshuman_kmr, you drawn NFA but not DFA for the language $\{(ab)^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ in given diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are tring to draw minimal DFA for the language $L = \{(ab)^n \mid n \geq 0\}$.

Non - deterministic finite automata (NFA) will be:

[image]

Add all missing transitions, so it will became deterministic finite automata (DFA):

[image]

Note that it is minimal DFA because minimization algorithm for DFA will give $3$ states only:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
 & a& b\\\hline
q_0 & q_1 & \text{dead}\\
q_1 & \text{dead} & q_0\\
\text{dead} & \text{dead} & \text{dead}\\
\end{array}
$$
Now, $\pi_0 = \{(q_0, \text{dead}), (q_1)\}$

$\pi_1 = \{(q_0), (\text{dead}), (q_1)\}$

$\pi_2 = \{(q_0), (q_1), (\text{dead})\}$

Therefore, $\pi_1 = \pi_2$. So, given DFA is minimal which has only $3$ states: $q_0, q_1,$ and, $\text{dead}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\{(ab)^n :n\geqslant 0\}$. Clearly $\epsilon\in L$, so we must have the starting state $q_0$ be an accepting state. Since $a\notin L$ and $b\notin L$, we must have states $q_a$, $q_b$ which are not accepting states. As $ab\in L$ and $bb\notin L$, it is clear that $q_a$ and $q_b$ must be distinct states. We define transitions $\delta(q,x)$ for pairs of states $(q,x)$ by
$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
q & x& \delta(q,x)\\\hline
q_0 & a & q_a\\
q_0 & b & q_b\\
q_a & b & q_0\\
q_b & a & q_0\\
\end{array}
$$
Since a string with two or more consecutive $a$'s is not in $L$, we see that a new state $q_{r,a}$ is needed for $\delta(q_a,a)$, and similarly a new state $q_{r,b}$ for $\delta(q_b,b)$. But any string which transitions into $q_{r,a}$ or $q_{r,b}$ is rejected, so there is no need to distinguish these states; let $q_r = q_{r,a} = q_{r,b}$. Define the rest of the transitions by
$$
\begin{array}{cc|c}
q & x& \delta(q,x)\\\hline
q_a & a & q_r\\
q_b & b & q_r\\
q_r & a & q_r\\
q_r & b & q_r\\
\end{array}
$$
then $M=(\{q_0,q_a,q_b,q_r\}, \{a,b\}, \delta, q_0, \{q_0\})$ is a DFA which recognizes $L$ with the minimum number of states.